# Readline, the Input Record Separator and Ruby

Tags: ruby, readline

In Ruby I'm looking to read data until I reach a delimiter or the end of the file.

I found this is possible by redefining `$/` or the `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` to my delimiter. However, with all the "features" in the Ruby language it seems hackey to change the value of a global to do this. Also, readline used to consume the delimiter, while not including it in what is returned.

Is there any other way to "read until" while consuming the delimiter that doesn't involve getting the values char by char in a loop?

Comment: What does "readline used to consume the delimiter while not it is included in what is returned" mean in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, all `readline`-style methods from `IO` accept separator string as an optional parameter:

```
>> s = StringIO.new('hello from string')
=> #<StringIO:0x52bf34>
>> s.readline ' '
=> "hello "
>> s.readline ' '
=> "from "
>> s.readline ' '
=> "string"
```

Comment: Excellent, how could I use that in a "f.each do |line|" or "while line s.gets"?

Comment: For the win! <!-- comment padding -->

Comment: So much for "hokey". I'd say an apology is needed to Ruby. Tell your computer you're sorry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the record separator as an argument to gets, e.g.:

```
while line = gets("\r")
  puts line
end
```