# What is the ruby -a command line switch?

Tags: ruby, string, command-line

From the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby) page:

```
 -a     Turns on auto-split mode when used with -n or -p.
        In auto-split mode, Ruby executes
              $F = $_.split
        at beginning of each loop.
```

Some questions come to mind:

- What happens when `-a` is used without `-n` or `-p`?
- What is `$F`?
- What happens at the end of the loop?
- How do I control which character is chosen to `split` on?
- How is `-a` intended to be used?

From another [reference page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_predefined_variables.htm):

```
$F      The variable that receives the output from split when -a is specified.
        This variable is set if the -a command-line option is specified
        along with the -p or -n option.
```

I'm still not sure what the `-a` switch is. Would appreciate an explanation but would appreciate some examples more.

Some things I've tried:

```
$ echo foo_bar_bar | ruby -ae
ruby: no code specified for -e (RuntimeError)
$ echo foo_bar_bar | ruby -ap
$ echo foo_bar_bar | ruby -ap '$_'
ruby: No such file or directory -- $_ (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-split mode is enabled with the `-a` switch. It enables the kind of text processing that [`awk`](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html) does by default.
In auto-split mode, ruby will read files given as arguments or `stdin`
one line at a time, and for each line:

1. automatically split the line, `$_`, into fields according to a field separator (designated by the `-F` flag)
2. assign the result to a variable named `$F`
3. do actions provided via the command-line.

After all lines are processed, the program exits or executes the [`END` block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326251/2909897). See this answer for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356889/2909897).

Auto-split mode is useful for working with tabular text files that have many `records` (`records` are lines unless the [record separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2463681/2909897) is changed) and a number of delimited `fields` in each line. 
For example, consider a `file` with content:

```
ADG:YUF:TGH
UIY:POG:YTH
GHJUR:HJKL:GHKIO
```

Then `ruby -F: -a -n -e 'puts $F[2]' file` prints the third field for each line:

```
$ ruby -F: -a -n -e 'puts $F[2]' file
TGH
YTH
GHKIO
```

In this case, `-F:` sets the field separator to `:`. `$F` is the array where the fields live after record (`$_`) is split. The actions after `-e` are executed for each line after it is split.

The `ruby` cli switches are very similar to those of `perl`. The `perl` cli makes this feature more convenient, see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches). For example, since `-a` is not useful without `-n`(or `-p`), in `perl`, `-F` enables `-a` implicitly, which in turn enables `-n`. This is not the case with `ruby`, all of the switches must be passed explicitly.
For examples of nice things that can be done with this kind of processing look for [`awk` one liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/).

Also, the `ruby` cli follows unix conventions for passing [command-line options](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/standard-options.html):

> Traditionally, UNIX command-line options consist of a dash, followed by one or more lowercase letters.

So the `-a` and `-n` [switches](https://superuser.com/a/1181719/277471) and `-e` [flag](https://superuser.com/a/1181719/277471) can be combined to achieve the same result:

```
$ ruby -F: -ane 'puts $F[2]' file
TGH
YTH
GHKIO
```

If this is interesting, check out some other [`ruby` one liners.](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-one-liners.html)